InvocationTargetException while using Koin for dependency Injection
I am working on an Android project using Jetpack Compose and I want to have access to my viewModel with the code that I will put bellow but when I try to do it using getNavViewModel I face too many Errors specially InvocationTargetException
can somebody help me please?!
val viewModel= getNavViewModel<MainViewModel>(
        parameters = {
            parametersOf(
                NetworkChecker(context).isInternetConnected
            )
        }
    )

this is my code for my viewModel
class MainViewModel(
    private val productRepository: ProductRepository,
    isInternetConnected: Boolean
) : ViewModel() {
    val dataProduct = mutableStateOf<List<Product>>(listOf())
    val showProgressBar = mutableStateOf(false)

    init {
        refreshAllDataFromNet(isInternetConnected)
    }
    fun refreshAllDataFromNet(isInternetConnected: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (isInternetConnected) {
                showProgressBar.value = true
            }

            val newDataProducts = async {
                productRepository.getProducts(isInternetConnected)
            }

            updateData(newDataProducts.await())

            showProgressBar.value = false
        }
    }
    private fun updateData(products: List<Product>) {
        dataProduct.value = products
    }
}

this is my module
val myModules = module {
    single { androidContext().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) }
    single { createApiService() }

    single<ProductRepository> { ProductRepositoryImpl(get()) }

    viewModel { (isNetConnected: Boolean) -> MainViewModel(get(), isNetConnected) }
}

I tried to use debugging to realize what is the specific problem but still it did not work

why wouldnt you just use koins by viewModel?

@tyczj what do you mean by that ?
How should I do it ?

https://insert-koin.io/docs/quickstart/android-compose#injecting-viewmodel-in-compose

@tyczj I am using Cokoin which is mostly the same as koin and it is now somehow hard to migrate to Koin
